# Split a String depending on its length

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, split

I have one input String to the program and I need to execute this String into my method, but I want to execute it if the character String is less than or equal to 20 characters, so I want to split this String into multiple Strings if the string is longer than 20 characters.
That is, the number of characters input String is 90 characters then become a 5 String 20 + 20 + 20 + 20 + 10 = 90.

I need each 20 characters String and last String do this code:

```
try {
            enMessage = AES.encrypt(key, message);
            sendSMS(contact, enMessage);
        } catch (Exception e)
```

so its could make each 20 characters is one message.

Comment: Usage of what you're searchin for is shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this:

```
package com.me;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
        public static List<String> splitMyString(String textValue, int textSize) {        
        ArrayList<String> myNewList= new ArrayList<String>((textValue.length() + textSize- 1) / textSize);

        for (int start = 0; start < textValue.length(); start += textSize) {
            myNewList.add(textValue.substring(start, Math.min(textValue.length(), start + textSize)));
        }
        System.out.println(myNewList.toString());
        return myNewList;
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test.splitMyString("1234546512312312312312365", 5);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Success   time: 0.1 memory: [12345, 46512, 31231, 23123,
>   12365]

Comment: sorry, wrong comment.. I'm on trying this code.

Comment: I have just updated the entire code tested and working with output.

Comment: thanks.. this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String's substring method to split the strings you want to.

You can read about how to use it here

[Java String Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

The best example of such code I have seen so far on this site is:

```
public class StringSplitter {

    /* regex was stolen from other stackoverflow answer*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String str : "123a4567a8sdfsdfsdgasfsdfsdgsdcvsdfdgdfsdf9".split("(?<=\\G.{20})"))
            System.out.format("\'%s\'%n", str);
    }

}
```

Comment: how to make each 20 characters become variable.. because here every 20 characters will be given method. thanks

Comment: @Viema, in the code above you can see a for-each loop. Each new String object consisting of 20 or less characters is stored in "str" variable

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
ArrayList<String> allstrings = new ArrayList<>();

if(inputstring.length() < 20) {
    //no spliting
} else {
    //if 90 char than 90/20=4.5
    float numberOfspliting = inputstring.length / 20f; 

    for(int i = 0; i < numberofspliting; i++){
        String split = inputstring.substring(i * 20, i * 20 + 20);
        allstrings.add(split);
    }
    //like 4.5-4=0.5
    float leftcharacters = numberofspliting - (int)numberofspliting;

    String lastsplit = inputstring.substring((int)numberofspliting * 20, (int)numberofspliting * 20 + leftcharacters * 20f);

    allstrings.add(lastsplit);

}//end if
```

Comment: still getting error in lastsplit and I don't know how to do method when all string stored in ArrayList. thanks